# PostgreSQL - retrieve all IDs in a tree for a given subnode

Tags: postgresql, recursive, tree

I have a non-binary tree of customer, and I need to obtain all the IDs in a tree for the given node.

The table is very simple, just an join table with a parent id and child id.
This is a representation of the tree I stored in my db.

[image]

In this example if I search for node 17 I need in return 14-17. If I search for 11 I need in return 1-6-5-4-8-11-12-7-2-10-3.

The order is not important. I only need the ID to avoid circularity when adding children to a node.

I created this query.
The ancestor part works fine, I retrieve all parent nodes, but for the descendants I have some trouble. I'm only able to retrieve some part of the tree.
For example, with node 11 I retrieve 4-10-6-11-7-8, so all right part of the tree is missing.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
-- starting node(s)
starting (parent, child) AS
(
  SELECT t.parent, t.child
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t
  WHERE t.child = :node or t.parent = :node
)
,
ancestors (parent, child) AS
(
  SELECT t.parent, t.child
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t
  WHERE t.parent IN (SELECT parent FROM starting)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.parent, t.child
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t JOIN ancestors AS a ON t.child = a.parent
),
descendants (parent, child) AS
(
  SELECT t.parent, t.child
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t
  WHERE t.parent IN (SELECT parent FROM starting) or t.child in (select child from starting)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.parent, t.child
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t JOIN ancestors AS a ON t.parent = a.child
)

table ancestors
union all
table descendants
```

### UPDATE

I see that many examples included in the tree table also the root in form (root_id, null).

In my case I don't have this record.

For example, taking the smallest tree 14->17, in my table I have only one record
parent, child

14      17

Comment: Depending on your workload and use case you may also want to consider [`ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ltree.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very primitive implementation:

It basically divides the problem into two subproblems:

- First find all the ancestors of the node in question (including the node itself). If the node has no parents, then this would be just itself.
- Then find the descendants of all those ancestors (including themselves). We may have several nodes in the `ancestors` result set, we may get duplicates here, so we use `UNION` (and not `UNION ALL`) to remove them.
- Note that the query will work even if the input node is a root with has no children.
- It will also work if the data set is not a forest of trees but an arbitrary  directed graph (where nodes can have more than one parent).

The query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
ancestors (parent) AS
(
  SELECT :node                      -- start with the given node
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.parent                   -- and find all its ancestors
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t JOIN ancestors AS a ON t.child = a.parent
),
descendants (customer) AS
(
  SELECT parent AS customer       -- now start with all the ancestors
  FROM ancestors
  UNION 
  SELECT t.child                  -- and find all their descendants
  FROM public.customerincustomer AS t JOIN descendants AS d ON t.parent = d.customer
)
SELECT customer
FROM descendants ;
```

Answer (score 5):

This function returns the parent level of `node_id`:

<sub>There is a 'level' row due there isn't a row (id, null) for parent row.</sub>

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_parent(node_id int)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
  WITH RECURSIVE get_parent AS
  (
      SELECT 
          t1.id, 
          t1.parent_id, 
          t1.name, 
          0 AS level
      FROM 
          tree t1
      WHERE 
          t1.id = node_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
          t2.id, 
          t2.parent_id, 
          t2.name,
          level+1
      FROM 
          tree t2 
      INNER JOIN 
          get_parent ON get_parent.parent_id = t2.id
  )
  SELECT
      id
  FROM
      get_parent
  ORDER BY
      level DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

select get_parent(7);

```
| get_parent |
| ---------: |
|          6 |
```

Now, next query returns the whole tree structure based on a parent node.

```
WITH RECURSIVE childs AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.id, 
        t1.parent_id, 
        t1.name
    FROM 
        tree t1
    WHERE 
        t1.id = get_parent(7)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        t2.id, 
        t2.parent_id, 
        t2.name
    FROM 
        tree t2 
    INNER JOIN 
        childs ON childs.id = t2.parent_id
)
SELECT
    id,
    parent_id,
    name
 FROM
    childs;
```

```
id | parent_id | name   
-: | --------: | :------
 6 |         1 | Node 6 
 4 |         6 | Node 4 
 8 |         6 | Node 8 
11 |         6 | Node 11
 7 |        11 | Node 7 
10 |         7 | Node 10
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cd7feb309d44805f5905438d6e389925)*

Comment: as i said, i don't have problem with ancestors. I need the whole tree.